# Prove that $503^{2000}-1$ is divisible by $625$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

> Prove that   $503^{2000}-1$ is divisible by $625$.

The problem is the middle of the above problems. Middle school students can understand thank you for the answer.

Comment: Your question in title and body are different. Do you know the generalization of Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: Have you calculated the Euler totient function of $625$? What theorems related to that have been covered in your class? Tell us more about that and your own thinking about this!

Comment: The problem is the middle of the above problems.Middle school students can understand thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Euler's phi theorem: If $(a,n) = 1$,
$$a^{\phi(n)} = 1 \mod n$$

Now $\phi(625) = \phi(5^4) = 5^4 - 5^3 = 500$. And $503$ is coprime with $625$.

Thus $$503^{500} = 1 \mod 625 $$
$$\Rightarrow 503^{2000} = 1 \mod 625$$

$\blacksquare$